# Using https on heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

I'm trying to get my app on heroku to be 'https everywhere'. So far the app is like this:

```
"use strict";

console.log('working');

//Initial setup
var path, https, privateKey, certificate, port, cdjshelp, util, cookies, oauth, twitter, crypto, _, options, express, auth, lodash, dust, dustjs,
    dustjsHelpers, commonDustjsHelpers, app, db, fs, mongoose, mongooseTimes, Comment, Bird, Sighting, Site, User,
    Backbone, io;

//node modules, express and dust declarations
path = require('path');
util = require('util');
fs = require('fs');
https = require('https');
privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./config/privatekey.pem').toString();
certificate = fs.readFileSync('./config/certificate.pem').toString();
crypto = require('crypto');

//APP Defn...
app = require('./config/appSetup')(dustjs);

//******** SERVER CONFIG **********//
var port = process.env['PORT'] = process.env.PORT || 4000; // Used by https on localhost

options = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening with https on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

I've used the openSSL CLI to generate a privatekey.pem and a certificate.pem and loaded them as options.

I know that heroku has a procedure if you're using DNS records to have the app serve to your own domain. I know that you have to go through the procedure listed [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint). I'm not remapping any urls or altering any records - my url is birdsapp.heroku.com.

Heroku uses piggyback SSL, so if you setup an http server your app will respond to https requests without any additional config. The problem there is that the http routes are still available, so I've stuck to setting an https server only - but it's timing out with nothing in the logs, so I think that there's a problem with the SSL setup.

Is the above setup correct? Is that the best way to do basic https server on heroku?

Comment: [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) is a tool by the EFF. It ensures use of HTTPS over HTTP in browsers (sans some broken sites). I don't believe it uses a public/private key pair. I don't read Heroku, but it looks like you are building a proxy server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's actually much simpler than that...

You simply create an http server:

```
//******** SERVER CONFIG **********//
var port = process.env['PORT'] = process.env.PORT || 4000;

http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening with http on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

and add a route redirect:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https')
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
    else
        next() /* Continue to other routes if we're not redirecting */
});
```

heroku takes care of the rest, setting up an http server which is a mirror of your http server  and uses their certs, etc.